RedirectToAction() is not working using ASP.NET Core
I'm learning ASP.NET Core and tried using RedirectToAction() method but somehow it's not working.
Here's the code for my LoginController:
[Route("[controller]")]
public class LogInController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Login Page";
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LogIn(LogInViewModel model) 
    {
        if (model.UserName != "Usertest" && model.Password != "Passtest")
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Denied", "Invalid Username/Password");
            return View("Index", model);
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(OTPInput), model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> OTPInput(LogInViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return View("InputOTP");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> OTPValidation([FromForm] string otp) 
    {
        if (otp != "123456")
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Invalid OTP", "Invalid OTP");
            return View("OTPInput");
        }

        return View();
    }
}

Here's my Index.cshtml markup with layout:
@model LogInViewModel

<div asp-validation-summary="All">
    <form asp-action="login" asp-controller="LogIn" method="post">
        <input asp-for="UserName" placeholder="Username" />
        <input asp-for="Password" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
    <span asp-validation-for="UserName" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Password" />
</div>

When I enter the correct username and password, I get redirected to
http://localhost:5142/LogIn/OTPInput?UserName=Usertest&Password=Passtest

I'm expecting to see the OTPInput.View but somehow the code doesn't reach the OTPInput() action method
It works when I use View("OTPInput", model) instead of RedirectToAction("OTPInput", "login", model)

The action name is OTPInput but you do return View("InputOTP"); which would point to a view named InputOTP. If this OTPInput vs InputOTP is intended, please accept this advice that it's not a good idea. If it's not intended, it can be a root of your issue here.

OTPInput is a POST endpoint. Redirects are always GET requests.

HTTP doesn't support redirection to a page using POST. When you redirect somewhere, the HTTP Location header tells the browser where to go, and the browser makes a GET request for that page.

Might be a good read Post/Redirect/Get.

I set it to HttpPost to hide the credentials on the URL. Is there any other way to achieve this?

@BenderBoy It does answer the question why it is not working. Thanks

When you pass the model as a parameter to RedirectToAction, it is treated as route data or query string parameters. This is why you're seeing the sensitive data (like ?UserName=...&Password=...) in the URL.
RedirectToAction() initiates a new HTTP GET request, which does not preserve the model state from the original POST request, because GET requests cannot maintain form data directly like POST actions do.

To avoid exposing sensitive information in the URL, you can either:

Use TempData to store data temporarily across requests.
Store sensitive information in session or cookies for later retrieval.


Changed the OTPInput method to a HTTPGet and working for me.
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Login Page";
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LogIn(ThisModel model)
    {
        if (model.UserName != "Usertest" && model.Password != "Passtest")
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Denied", "Invalid Username/Password");
            return View("Index", model);
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(OTPInput), model);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> OTPInput(ThisModel viewModel)
    {
        return View("Hello");
    }

    public class ThisModel
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }


Using GET will display the username and password on the URL
